# How can I find out what broke Angular's automatic change detection?

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular project and it seems like automatic change detection stopped working.

To verify this I created a new Angular project and added the part of code which made me realize that automatic change detection doesn't work.

It's really simple:

```
export class ConfirmEmailPageComponent implements OnInit {
loaded: boolean = false;

constructor(
  private accountService: AccountService,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.accountService
    .confirmEmailAddress(this.route.snapshot.queryParams)
    .subscribe(
      d => console.log(d),
      err => console.log(err),
      () => {
        this.loaded = true;
        //this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

In the template I just put

```
{{ loaded | json }}
```

to see if it changes to true after the request has finished.

While it works on the new project, in my old one I need to uncomment the

```
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

and it starts to work.

The project is quite large already so I would need to add the pieces one by one to the new project :/

Is there a way to find out what part of the code broke the automatic change detection?

Comment: I would check `NgZone.isInAngularZone()`

Comment: I just tried this and it returns true. So shouldn't it work without detectChanges() then?

Comment: If your component is not OnPush then yes.

Comment: This is strange because I wasn't using OnPush

Comment: Why not move `this.loaded = true;` to observer callback. Maybe it's because your observable is not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I made some mistakes setting up my auth guard. I still don't really understand why this happened and I'm still using the detectChanges function of the ChangeDetectorRef for this cause. I was actually thinking the whole automatic change detection was corrupted.